# Как сделать картинку цветной на неактивной кнопке?

Tags: winforms

У меня есть некоторая `Button`, создаваемая из скрипта. Я делаю её неактивной с помощью `button.enabled = false` и устанавливаю ей изображение из ресурсов с помощью `button.Image = Resources.Tile1`.

Однако при работе программы изображение становится черно-белым.
Как я могу сделать так, чтобы картинка не меняла цвет вне зависимости от активности кнопки?

Спасибо

Comment: Штатными средствами WinForms это не изменить. Это базовый механизм отрисовки контролов из WinAPI и задается стилем (набором битовых флагов) по правилам WinAPI. Можете Сделать собственный Button и поменять поведение, либо использовать костыль и вместо отключения кнопки просто отписать ее от события Click, но это не лучший вариант, т.к. кнопка останется кликабельной, просто не будет ничего делать при клике, что может сбивать с толку пользователя.